# How do I run JUnit tests using Maven via console?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, junit

I'm doing the https://spring.academy/courses/spring-framework-essentials/lessons/spring-essentials-aop-lab-demo and struggled with the console output until I ran it inside the Spring Tool Suite 4 and looked at the console window there.

When I run the tests from the lab folder using this command `./mvnw -pl 22-aop test`, I don't get any console output. I assume that mvnw is not executing JUnit tests here but something else?

How could I run the same test using just the console instead of using the STS4 IDE?

[image]

**labs/22-aop/pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>22-aop</artifactId>
    <organization>
        <name>Spring Training</name>
        <url>https://spring.io/training</url>
    </organization>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>io.spring.training.core-spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>parentProject</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.23</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.spring.training.core-spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>00-rewards-common</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jamonapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jamon</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Skip these tests.  They won't pass until the student completes the lab. -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/RewardNetworkTests.java</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/DBExceptionHandlingAspectTests.java</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/LoggingAspectTests.java</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/RepositoryPerformanceLogTest.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**labs/pom.xml**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>io.spring.training.core-spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>parentProject</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.23</version>
    <organization>
        <name>Spring Training</name>
        <url>https://spring.io/training</url>
    </organization>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <!-- Versions of other dependencies not in spring IO. -->
        <easymock.version>4.3</easymock.version>
        <hibernate.jmx.version>3.5.6-Final</hibernate.jmx.version>
        <jamon.version>2.82</jamon.version>
        <spring-security.version>5.8.0</spring-security.version>

        <java.version>11</java.version>

        <!-- Enable maven support for Servlet 3 - no web.xml -->
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

        <!-- Add JAXB that is dropped in JDK 9 -->
        <jaxb-api.version>2.3.0</jaxb-api.version>

        <!-- Without this, Eclipse will flag an error on pom.xml -->
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!--
        // Although we are not using Spring Boot until Day 3, we do use
        // SpringApplication which is a Spring Boot class. The starters
        // are also a convenient way of pulling in the most common
        // Spring and Testing dependencies.
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Needed for Spring's JdbcTemplate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <!-- Dependencies we may need, and their versions -->
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Course specific -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.spring.training.core-spring</groupId>
                <artifactId>00-rewards-common</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.spring.training.core-spring</groupId>
                <artifactId>01-rewards-db</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Other -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jmx</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.jmx.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
                <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
                <version>${easymock.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.jamonapi</groupId>
                <artifactId>jamon</artifactId>
                <version>${jamon.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.maven.plugin}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <!-- Ensure resources are exported correctly - conflict with Spring Boot -->
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Set Java version -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Set Project Natures -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <sourceIncludes>
                        <sourceInclude>**/*.*</sourceInclude>
                    </sourceIncludes>
                    <!-- All of them are listed manually to solve a limitation of the
                        mvn eclipse plugin (https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-2938).
                        This might cause some issues when migrating to the next version of Eclipse/STS)
                        also see spring-intro/pom.xml (projectnatures defined explicitely there
                        as well) -->
                    <projectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature</projectnature>
                    </projectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <name>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</name>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Ensure resources are handled correctly -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
    <modules>
        <!--
          // KEEP IN SYNC WITH SLIDES
          -->
        <!-- Section: Shared -->
        <module>00-rewards-common</module>
        <module>01-rewards-db</module>

        <!-- Section: Spring Essentials -->
        <!-- Day 1 -->
        <module>10-spring-intro</module>
        <module>10-spring-intro-solution</module>
        <module>12-javaconfig-dependency-injection</module>
        <module>12-javaconfig-dependency-injection-solution</module>
        <module>16-annotations</module>
        <module>16-annotations-solution</module>

        <!-- Day 2 -->
        <module>22-aop</module>
        <module>22-aop-solution</module>
        <module>24-test</module>
        <module>24-test-solution</module>
        <module>26-jdbc</module>
        <module>26-jdbc-solution</module>
        <module>28-transactions</module>
        <module>28-transactions-solution</module>

        <!-- Section: Spring Boot -->

        <!-- Day 3 -->
        <module>30-jdbc-boot-solution</module>
        <module>32-jdbc-autoconfig</module>
        <module>32-jdbc-autoconfig-solution</module>
        <module>34-spring-data-jpa</module>
        <module>34-spring-data-jpa-solution</module>
        <module>36-mvc</module>
        <module>36-mvc-solution</module>
        
        <!-- Day 4 -->
        <module>38-rest-ws</module>
        <module>38-rest-ws-solution</module>
        <module>40-boot-test</module>
        <module>40-boot-test-solution</module>
        <module>42-security-rest</module>
        <module>42-security-rest-solution</module>
        <module>44-actuator</module>
        <module>44-actuator-solution</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you please include the pom.xml file of that project?

Comment: You can download the whole lab here https://github.com/vmware-tanzu-learning/spring-pro-code/releases/download/core-spring-release-1.18.1/core-spring-labfiles.zip It is part 22 that I'm working on. I have added the pom.xml from it to the question. But there is another one in the root of the labs. I'm not sure if that matters, I have added that one as well.

Comment: The test is explicitely excluded in your POM in this line: `<exclude>**/LoggingAspectTests.java</exclude>`

Comment: But how is it able to run the test in Spring Tool Suit and show the log then? And removing them from the exclude list doesn't make any difference when I run `./mvnw -pl 22-aop test`